# Hp proliant ml110 g6 stops at purple screen on boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, hp

I know this has been answered elsewhere extensively, however the solutions don't seem to work for me. I am trying to install ubuntu server 20.04 onto a HP Proliant ml110 g6. I am using the net installer and the installation goes well. But when i try to boot up, it shows an ubuntu loading screen with four dots underneath it, and the goes completely purple apart from a black space with a cursor in it. Typing things does nothing, and Ctrl Alt delete shows the loading picture again and reboots. I saw this was to do with graphics drivers, but i don't think my computer has them as there are none in any specifications i can find and its a server.

Edit: I can install a 32 bit server, and it works, however my processor is definitely 64 bit.

Comment: Are you able to boot with a USB or DVD instead?

Comment: i can use a usb to do the installation but i don't think there is a live server image.